# Writing Unit Tests of file readers with Scala and SBT

Tags: unit-testing, scala, sbt

I need to write a unit test that reads lines from several files, parses them and creates the object I require. When using sbt to run the tests, it says that there is no server started:

```
RuntimeException: There is no started application (Play.scala:46)
```

The problem arises when trying to use a file reader operation such as:

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath)
```

and the compiler expects something mocked.

How should I approach to this problem, should I make a method that reads the files and converts them to strings, and then test the parse method itself? But then I would have to create a test for the fileReader, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem is software development, of how to simply mock external dependendencies. Usually a good approach is to wrap all external calls with minimal code (so there isn't a lot of chance of bugs), and then mock that.

In your case you could do something like this:

```
class FileHandler {
  def getFile(filePath: String) = {
    val src = Source.fromFile(filePath)
    val lines = src.getLines()
    // Just to have some resource management and close resources after they have been read.
    new Iterator[String] {
      def hasNext: Boolean = {
        if(!lines.hasNext) Try { src.close() }
        lines.hasNext
      }
      def next(): String = lines.next()
    }
  }
  // Other stuff you would want to do
  def saveFile(....) = ???
}
```

Now we can mock this:

```
val fileHandler = mock[FileHandler]
val iterator = Seq("line1", "line2", "line3").toIterator
fileHandler.getFile("/some/file/path") returns iterator
```

This gives you full control of what path returns what contents and leaves out the whole file handling part. It's not an easy task, so I would like to read other answers, about how to solve this!